# Neater way to display custom class in ASP.net webpage?

Tags: asp.net, html-table

Currently I do the following:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Prospect";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Prospect.Name</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Address1:</b>
        </td>
        <td>@ViewBag.Prospect.Address1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Postcode:</b>
        </td>
        <td>@ViewBag.Prospect.Postcode
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Tel:</b>
        </td>
        <td>@ViewBag.Prospect.Tel
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Email:</b>
        </td>
        <td>@ViewBag.Prospect.Email
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, there is ALOT of code, its messy, and well, I currently show 4 columns when I need 15!!!

**Surely there must be a neater syntax way of doing this?** Alternatives to using a table? Note: All columns must be in line. and also note, that this is just desiring 1 record to be shown. Not a list of records.

I know in ROR, it was much neater than this. I think i used formtastic or similar to display info. (I dont want to edit info, just view it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minimize this, you may use reflection in order to achieve at the cleanest level.

Let this be your `ViewModel`:

```
public class Prospect
{
    public string Name { get; set }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    public string  Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is your `Action`:

```
public ActionResult ViewProspect()
{
    Prospect prospect = new Prospect { 
        Name = "Jackson", 
        Address = "21, Some hills", 
        PostCode = "90210", 
        Tel = "505123412", 
        Email = "jack@son.com" 
    };

    Func<string, string> getStringValue = (value) => value == null ? string.Empty : value.ToString();

    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> prospectKeyValue = typeof(Prospect).GetProperties().Select(
                p => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(p.Name, getStringValue(p.GetValue(prospect, null))));

    ViewBag.Prospect = prospectKeyValue;
    View();
}
```

And here is your simplified `View`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Prospect";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Prospect.Single(p => p.Key == "Name").Value</h2>
<table>
    @foreach(var keyValue in ViewBag.Prospect)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>@keyValue.Key</b>
            </td>
            <td>@keyValue.Value
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks a billion. Trying it out now.

Comment: Provides a problem in the case of Integer fields. They dont seem to show

Comment: Just change from `p.GetValue(prospect, null) as string` to `p.GetValue(prospect, null).ToString()`.

Comment: and what about the case where the value in prospect is null? thanks

Comment: I went with `(p.Name, (p.GetValue(prospect, null) ?? "").ToString())` to save the extra function. But thanks! :)